# Trouble making nodes inside two circles with intersection in LATEX using tikz

Tags: latex, nodes, intersection, tikz

I have made a social graph, as you can see below, but couldn't figure out a way to make the nodes inside two circles in which the nodes in the middle (F, D, K, M) are placed in the intersection of the two circles.

And is there a simple way to label left circle, right circle and the intersection?

Here is the code and thank you so much in advance:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
    \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node (B) at (0,3) {B};
    \node (C) at (2,3) {C};
    \node (E) at (1,-1.5) {E};
    \node (G) at (1,1.5) {G};

    \node (F) at (5,2) {F} ;
    \node (D) at (4,1) {D};
    \node (K) at (5,0) {K};
    \node (M) at (4,-1) {M};

    \node (H) at (8.5,0) {H};
    \node (I) at (9,2.5) {I};
    \node (J) at (8,1.5) {J};
    \node (N) at (7.5,-1.5) {N};
    \node (L) at (7,3) {L} ;
    \node (Q) at (9.5,1) {Q} ;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
    every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
    every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}]
    \draw (A) -> (G);
    \draw (B) -- (A);
    \draw (B) -- (C);
    \draw (B) -- (G);
    \draw (E) -- (G);
    \draw (E) -- (A);
    \draw (G) -- (C);
    \draw (L) -- (I);
    \draw (H) -- (J);
    \draw (Q) -- (H);
    \draw (I) -- (J);
    \draw (N) -- (H);
    \draw (Q) -- (J);

    \draw (A) -> (D);
    \draw (E) -- (M);
    \draw (E) -- (D);
    \draw (G) -- (D);
    \draw (G) -- (F);
    \draw (C) -- (F);
    \draw (C) -- (M);
    \draw (N) -- (K);
    \draw (N) -- (F);
    \draw (N) -- (M);
    \draw (L) -- (F);
    \draw (J) -- (F);
    \draw (H) -- (F);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

UPDATE:

After I added these 2 lines:

\draw (2,0.7) circle (4cm);

\draw (7,0.7) circle (4cm);
 I get this:
[image]

I am only left with coloring the intersection so below these 2 lines I added:

%\draw clip circle (4cm);

%\fill[gray] (2,0.7) circle (4cm);

Which did the job but one of the circles hides its nodes!!
[image]

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
    \draw (2,0.7) circle (4cm);
    \clip (7,0.7) circle (4cm);
    \fill[gray] (2,0.7) circle (4cm);
    \draw (7,0.7) circle (4cm);
\end{scope}

\node[below=4.5cm of circle1] {Circle 1};
\node[below=4.5cm of circle2] {Circle 2};
\node[below=4cm of circle1,xshift=2.5cm] {Intersection};

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
    \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node (B) at (0,3) {B};
    \node (C) at (2,3) {C};
    \node (E) at (1,-1.5) {E};
    \node (G) at (1,1.5) {G};

    \node (F) at (5,2) {F} ;
    \node (D) at (4,1) {D};
    \node (K) at (5,0) {K};
    \node (M) at (4,-1) {M};

    \node (H) at (8.5,0) {H};
    \node (I) at (9,2.5) {I};
    \node (J) at (8,1.5) {J};
    \node (N) at (7.5,-1.5) {N};
    \node (L) at (7,3) {L} ;
    \node (Q) at (9.5,1) {Q} ;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
    every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
    every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}]
    \draw (A) -> (G);
    \draw (B) -- (A);
    \draw (B) -- (C);
    \draw (B) -- (G);
    \draw (E) -- (G);
    \draw (E) -- (A);
    \draw (G) -- (C);
    \draw (L) -- (I);
    \draw (H) -- (J);
    \draw (Q) -- (H);
    \draw (I) -- (J);
    \draw (N) -- (H);
    \draw (Q) -- (J);

    \draw (A) -> (D);
    \draw (E) -- (M);
    \draw (E) -- (D);
    \draw (G) -- (D);
    \draw (G) -- (F);
    \draw (C) -- (F);
    \draw (C) -- (M);
    \draw (N) -- (K);
    \draw (N) -- (F);
    \draw (N) -- (M);
    \draw (L) -- (F);
    \draw (J) -- (F);
    \draw (H) -- (F);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Without seeing how you added the clip and fill instructions, I can't really tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Thank for your answers but that's not what I meant though. I meant nodes placed "inside" a circle. I updated my code which solved most of what I am looking for. Please have a look

Comment: So, it was a matter of ordering my code!! it makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Do you know what is the best way to put a label underneath the intersection?

Comment: I've updated the code with labels underneath each set of nodes.